# Silverlight Browser Close Event

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-2.0

When the user closes the browser that hosts my Silverlight 2 Application I need to call a web service that would log the user out. I am aware of the Application_Exit event, however when I call my service in that event nothing happens.  I presume that the connection to my service is already closed by then.

Is there another event that I should use?

Please help.

Comment: A little more context would be helpful. What exactly happens when the user 'logs out' over the web service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do it. Calling a service at application exit is not supported by Silverlight. You need the service to clean itself up, possibly with the application telling the service every few minutes/hours as appropriate tto delay the cleanup.
[Link to Silverlight Forums and the same question](http://silverlight.net/themes/silverlight/forums/thread.aspx?ThreadID=21704)

Comment: The link is broken - this appears to be the correct one: http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/20279.aspx